# What does the -v stand for in mqttjs subscribe command

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

It it no where in the readme file: [MQTTJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt)

```
mqtt sub -t 'hello' -h 'test.mosquitto.org' -v
```

Question:
**What does the -v stand for in the subscribe line of mqttjs?**

Comment: Without knowing the command in question, my money's on "Verbose"

Comment: Have you try to read docs? Right under string you've copied here there is "See mqtt help <command> for the command help"

Comment: @Basic It was verbose I just went into the source code... should have jsut did that before

Comment: @MatthewHarwood No worries, we've all done it. I'd suggest deletion as this doesn't add much value for other visitors.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, the -v refers to 'verbose'

source: https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/blob/master/bin/sub.js#L59 line 28

Comment: this link better https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/blob/master/doc/subscribe.txt#L25